# Python UDF for Pig: datatype conversion error

Tags: hadoop, user-defined-functions, apache-pig

I'm using a Python UDF which causes an error during the reduce phase.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to org.apache.pig.data.DataByteArray
```

Here's the code for the UDF:

```
import math
outputSchema("score:double")
def confidenceLowerBound(numerator, denominator, constant):
    raw_score = numerator * 1.0 / denominator
    normalized_interval = math.sqrt( raw_score * (1 - raw_score) / denominator )

    wilson_score = raw_score - constant * normalized_interval
    return wilson_score
```

This is how I call the udf in pig.

```
register 'confidence_interval_compute.py' using jython as pyutils;
...
..
A = FOREACH A GENERATE $0, $1, $2, $3, $4, pyutils.confidenceLowerBound($3, $4, 4) AS score PARALLEL 20;
```

Comment: How does the schema of `A` look like which you iterate over? Which Pig version do you use?

Comment: I hope this is a typo, but you're missing the @ before `outputSchema` (ie. `@outputSchema("score:double")` . The decorator will not be invoked if this is missing, meaning Pig will not know the output is a double.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ian Stevents pointed out in the comments, this is because you are having a typo in the decorator.

You should use

```
@outputSchema("score:double")
```